# Table headings displaying for each new row in table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I am creating a table that displays the data from a table in my database. Each time I add a new row in the table, the table headings display above each row. How do I get it so there is only the headings at the top of the table?
here is my code

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT fName, sName, DOB
            FROM Customertbl";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
     {
    ?>                                          
<table style ="width:100%">
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Date of Birth</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["fName"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["sName"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["DOB"] ?></td>
</tr>
</table>    
        <?php
    }
} 
?>
```

The output on my page is like this

```
Firstname Surname Date of Birth
James     Scott   01/01/2000 
Firstname Surname Date of Birth
James     Scott   01/01/2000
```

I want it like this

```
Firstname Surname Date of Birth
James     Scott   01/01/2000 
James     Scott   01/01/2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just get head out while loop:

```
<table style ="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
    </tr>
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT fName, sName, DOB
                FROM Customertbl";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         {
        ?>                                          

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["fName"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["sName"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["DOB"] ?></td>
    </tr>

            <?php
        }
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but now I have another problem, I put the table in a div so I can style in my css but now it only puts one of the row of data in the div and the rest outside of it.